# Are lines connecting centroids of triangles orthogonal to the shared side?

Tags: geometry

I have a restriction for a program I'm writing. The line segment connecting the calculation points inside two polygons must be orthogonal to the side shared by the polygons.

The simplest thing for me to do would be to use the centroids of the polygons. I'm using triangles.

I assume this is only true for certain cases/types of triangles. If so, could you point me to the theorem(s) for this?

Comment: Could you please add more detail to the question? Maybe an example or a picture of what you mean by "calculation points". Or maybe more context?

Comment: You mean like two squares on either side of a side of each square? Are both polygons in the same plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are lines connecting centroids of triangles orthogonal to the shared side?

No, they are not:

[image: Counterexample]

There certainly are situations where this is the case, with regular triangles among them, but if you want to describe *all* such situations, then I'd do that exactly using the orthogonality between shared side and centroid. So I know of no simpler description.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I expected. Would you be willing to share how you made your figure? I need a graphical way to explain this and generating figures like yours would help.

Comment: @chasely: I used [Cinderella](http://cinderella.de/) which you can download for free.